# Parabolic animation for div in Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in Javascript.I want to an animation like that:

firstly there is a closed bag picture.When person click on the bag picture, the picture will change to opened bag.

Then, objects ( I dont know javascipt literary, I mean divs which contain image ) start to get out of the bag with parabolic animation.When the animation finish, all items will be on same based (align) with bag.

Then, objects  will start to go to right.Every items except first item has delay as ms also space between.Like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div.2").animate({left: '70vw'});
    $("div.1").delay( 800 ).animate({left: '40vw'});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Start Animation</button>

<p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>

<div class="1" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
x
</div>
<div class="2" style="background:pink;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
```

**recent form:**

http://migrate2.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/ball/ball.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .bag {
        display: block;
        width: 240px;
        height: 120px;

        background-image: url("http://migrate2.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/ball/New Project240x120.png");
        position: relative;
        top: 150px;
       margin-left: auto!important;
        margin-right: auto!important;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .holder {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .mask {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 120px;
        height: 60px;

        display: block;
    }

    .dot {
        position: absolute;
     left: 95px;
        top: 0;

    }

    .dot::after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 150px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dot1::after {
        background-image: url("http://migrate2.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/ball/New Project (7).png");
    }

    .dot2::after {
        background-image: url("http://migrate2.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/ball/New Project (8).png");
    }

    .bag.open,
    .bag.open .mask {
        background-image: url("http://migrate2.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/ball/New%20Project%20(1)240x120.png");
    }

    .bag.open .dot1 {
        animation: xAxis1 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.21, 1);
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    .bag.open .dot1::after {
        animation: yAxis1 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.27, 0.07, 1.64);
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    .bag.open .dot2 {
        animation: xAxis2 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.21, 1);
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    .bag.open .dot2::after {
        animation: yAxis2 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.27, 0.07, 1.64);
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @keyframes yAxis1 {
        50% {
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.21, 1);
            transform: translateY(-100px);
        }
        100% {
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.21, 1);
            transform: translateY(70px);
        }
    }

    @keyframes xAxis1 {
        100% {
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.27, 0.07, 1.64);
            transform: translateX(150px);
        }
    }

    @keyframes yAxis2 {
        50% {
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.21, 1);
            transform: translateY(-100px);
        }
        100% {
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.21, 1);
            transform: translateY(70px);
        }
    }

    @keyframes xAxis2 {
        100% {
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.27, 0.07, 1.64);
            transform: translateX(-150px);
        }
    }


</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".bag").on("click", function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("open");
        });
    });




</script>



</head>



<body>

<div class="bag">
    <div class="dot dot1">
        Ekipman
    </div>
    <div class="dot dot2">
        Kıyafet
    </div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here is an article to help you: https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/curved-path-animations-in-css/ If you have links to the closed and open bag pictures, I can create a snippet for you to experiment with.

Comment: yes , there are . thanks I will post it

Comment: @BlackWiCKED here is : https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/old-brown-opened-closed-suitcase_2872088.htm

Comment: First I suggested a CSS solution, then I realized that you wanted a JS animation... So I did a little extra research and found this library: https://github.com/yairEO/pathAnimator/ Can do a bag / objects demo with it later if you are still interested.

Comment: @BlackWiCKED it works when every click on items.i want that it changes to open bag only first click because when click on equipment or clothes, it will open woocommerce category page.how can i do it, can you help me again please? i editted question to add latest form with code and link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some basic CSS animation, hopefully helps you to get started.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bag").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.bag {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #ff0;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.holder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ff0;
  display: block;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px;
  top: 0;
}

.dot::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dot1::after {
  background-color: #333;
}

.dot2::after {
  background-color: #00a;
}

.bag.open,
.bag.open .mask {
  background-color: #f00;
}

.bag.open .dot1 {
  animation: xAxis1 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.21, 1);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.bag.open .dot1::after {
  animation: yAxis1 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.27, 0.07, 1.64);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.bag.open .dot2 {
  animation: xAxis2 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.21, 1);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.bag.open .dot2::after {
  animation: yAxis2 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.27, 0.07, 1.64);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes yAxis1 {
  50% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.21, 1);
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
  100% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.21, 1);
    transform: translateY(70px);
  }
}

@keyframes xAxis1 {
  100% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.27, 0.07, 1.64);
    transform: translateX(150px);
  }
}

@keyframes yAxis2 {
  50% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.21, 1);
    transform: translateY(-80px);
  }
  100% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.21, 1);
    transform: translateY(70px);
  }
}

@keyframes xAxis2 {
  100% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.27, 0.07, 1.64);
    transform: translateX(-120px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="bag">
    <div class="dot dot1"></div>
    <div class="dot dot2"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Second solution. This one is with pure JavaScript animations, using https://github.com/yairEO/pathAnimator library and https://codepen.io/anthonydugois/pen/mewdyZ tool for drawing paths.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var paths = [
    "M 160 120 Q 160 30 210 30 Q 270 30 240 180",
    "M 160 120 Q 160 30 110 30 Q 60 40 60 180",
    "M 160 120 Q 160 30 210 50 Q 280 80 300 180"
  ];
  var walkers = [];

  function AnimateWalker(walker, index) {
    this.pathAnimator = new PathAnimator(paths[index], {
      duration: 3,
      step: this.step.bind(this),
      reverse: false,
      onDone: this.finish.bind(this)
    });

    this.walker = walker;
  }

  AnimateWalker.prototype = {
    start: function() {
      this.startOffset = (this.reverse || this.speed < 0) ? 100 : 0;
      this.pathAnimator.start();
    },

    step: function(point, angle) {
      var stretchFactor = 1,
        scale = 25 + this.pathAnimator.percent / 4;

      scale = (scale / 30) + 0.5;

      this.walker.style.cssText = "top:" + point.y * stretchFactor + "px;" +
        "left:" + point.x * stretchFactor + "px;" +
        "transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg) scale(" + scale + ");";
    },

    finish: function() {
      this.pathAnimator.stop();
    },

    resume: function() {
      this.pathAnimator.start(this.speed, this.step, this.reverse, this.pathAnimator.percent, this.finish, this.easing);
    }
  }

  function generateWalker(walkerObj) {
    var newAnimatedWalker = new AnimateWalker(walkerObj, walkers.length);
    walkers.push(newAnimatedWalker);
    return newAnimatedWalker;
  }

  $(".box").on("click", function() {

    if (!$('.wrapper').hasClass("open")) {

      $('img').each(function(k, v) {
        generateWalker(v).start();
      });
      $('.wrapper').addClass("open");
    } else {

      $('.wrapper').removeClass("open");
      $(walkers).each(function(k, v) {
        v.finish();
      });
      walkers = [];
    }

  });

});
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 480px;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.ground {
  background-color: #0a0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 120px;
  left: 120px;
  background: url('https://st2.depositphotos.com/1431107/6391/v/950/depositphotos_63919095-stock-illustration-open-and-closed-box-icon.jpg');
  background-size: 220%;
  background-position: -7px -20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.wrapper.open .box {
  background-position: -108px -20px;
}

.wrapper.open img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/yairEO/pathAnimator@master/pathAnimator.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="ground"></div>

  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yairEO/pathAnimator/master/demos/2/fire.png" />
  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yairEO/pathAnimator/master/demos/2/fire.png" />
  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yairEO/pathAnimator/master/demos/2/fire.png" />

</div>
```